# Proper way to operate collections in StateFlow

Tags: kotlin, collections, kotlin-flow

I'm creating MutableStateFlow like this:

```
val intSet = MutableStateFlow(HashSet<Int>())
```

And in some moment later I want to update collection in this flow:

```
intSet.value.add(0)
```

And this doesn't seem to work (the collection updates, but observers are not notified).
The way that I found it working:

```
val list = HashSet<Int>(intSet.value)
list.add(0)
intSet.value = list
```

But it creates copy of the collection, so it doesn't look proper for me. Is there any simpler way to update collection in StateFlow?

Comment: That isn’t creating a copy of the set. It’s setting the same set instance to the property. Anyway, in most cases I think it would be poor design to have a flow of a mutable collection because the behavior is ambiguous to the collector, which won’t know for sure if it’s allowed to cache the value, or modify the contents, or can rely on the contents remaining the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`MutableFlow` does not check for changes in the content of collections. Only when the collection reference has changed it will emit the change.

Use immutable `Set` and use the `+=` operator to add new elements. This will basically, create new `Set` and will trigger the change.

```kotlin
val intSetFlow = MutableStateFlow(setOf<Int>())
intSetFlow.value += 0
```

Comment: what about hashmap?

Comment: @user924

`
    val mapFlow = MutableStateFlow(mapOf<String,Int>())
            mapFlow.value += "yes" to 1
`