# jetpack compose - How to do state hoisting for a parsed complex object?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

So, in my dataset, I'm storing a special string. This string must be parsed into a tree for user manipulation (view, edit, delete, merge, adding nodes ..etc). For the node addition and deletion, I need to get the cursor position from the active text field. At every manipulation step, I convert the tree back into its string representation and store that into the dataset, which triggers UI updates and so on.

However, I now have 3 different sources of truth:

- `ViewModel` containing the Stateflow from the database of the unparsed string

```
private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(MyUnparsedStringFromDB())
val uiState: StateFlow<MyUnparsedStringFromDB> = _uiState.asStateFlow()
```

- `mutableStateOf` containing the tree object in TreeComponent

```
@Composable
fun TreeComponent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    unparsedString: String,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
) {
    var root: MyTreeNode by remember { mutableStateOf(unparsedString.toTree()) }
    val onNodeValueChange: (MyTreeNode, String) -> Unit = { node, newValue ->
        node.text = newValue
        onValueChange(root.toString())
    }
    ...
    // recursive logic to call NodeComponent on each node
    NodeComponent(node, onNodeValueChange)
    ...
}
```

- `mutableStateOf` containing the textfield of the current node in NodeComponent

```
@Composable
fun NodeComponent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    node: MyTreeNode,
    onNodeValueChange: (MyTreeNode, String) -> Unit,
) {
    var textState by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(node.text)) }
    BasicTextField(
        value = textState,
        onValueChange = {
            onNodeValueChange(node, it.text)
            textState = it
        }
        // ...
    )
}
```

Initially, this worked great when my goal was rendering this tree or editing the `node.text` field. But the moment I try to do more complex operations like node splitting, addition, deletion, and merging, it becomes a HUGE headache.

Right now, for example, when I try to split the node in half at the current cursor position, the tree is perfectly updated as expected, and the correct string representation is saved in the dataset. But the `textfield` state update is not triggered unless I leave the UI then come back to it. I tried to force the update by overriding `MyTreeNode.equals` function to always output false as [suggested by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65382175/mutablestateflow-force-update-notify-collector) but it didn't work

So, how should I correctly do state hoisting when the object in question is complex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `textState` in the `NodeComponent` is getting remembered and the only way to change it is by editing the corresponding `BasicTextField`. To keep the source of truth in the view model i suggest to pass `NodeComponent` only the parts of `MyTreeNode` that are needed, like `text` property in my example.

Also you should try adding your tree String as a key to the root node's `remember`. This way `root` will be updated every time `unparsedString` changes.

```
@Composable
fun TreeComponent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    unparsedString: String,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
) {
    var root: MyTreeNode by remember(unparsedString) { mutableStateOf(unparsedString.toTree()) }
    ...
    // recursive logic to call NodeComponent on each node
    NodeComponent(
        nodeText = node.text,
        onNodeValueChange = {
            node.text = it
            onValueChange(root.toString())
        }
    )
    ...
}

private fun NodeComponent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    nodeText: String,
    onNodeValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
) {
    TextField(
        value = nodeText,
        onValueChange = onNodeValueChange
        // ...
    )
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know about passing keys to `remember`! I added the key to `root` and refactored `NodeComponent` to only receive the text instead of the node, but I still needed the `textState` for other tasks (finding the current cursor position) so I passed the text as its key. everything works in harmony now!